# Which Cloud Server will be easy to learn and use

Tags: server, cloud

I'm doing my final year project in Cloud Computing.  I request you people to suggest me a cloud server which i can use for my project.  Please give me a server in which i can use Java as programming language and which doesn't requires high hardware configurations.

Comment: This question may not be best suited for this website. Have you been to ServerFault ? Also, you may be able to leverage Docker to give you what you need from a hardware / server config perspective.

Comment: What is your final project objective? Build a Java application and run it in cloud or build dev environment in cloud?

Comment: Building a java application and running it in cloud